# Is there an API to retrieve latest versions of firefox release numbers for all release channels?

Tags: firefox

I am looking for an api to retrieve latest versions of firefox release numbers for all release channels. Something like this https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/
but is there a link which has the release numbers for all channels like aurora etc..

Answer (score 11):

I found this link useful, incase anybody else finds it useful:
https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json

Answer (score 0):

One could make a GET request to

```
https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json

The JSON formatted result is 
{
    "FIREFOX_AURORA": "",
    "FIREFOX_DEVEDITION": "107.0b9",
    "FIREFOX_ESR": "102.4.0esr",
    "FIREFOX_ESR_NEXT": "",
    "FIREFOX_NIGHTLY": "108.0a1",
    "FIREFOX_PINEBUILD": "",
    "LAST_MERGE_DATE": "2022-10-17",
    "LAST_RELEASE_DATE": "2022-10-18",
    "LAST_SOFTFREEZE_DATE": "2022-10-13",
    "LAST_STRINGFREEZE_DATE": "2022-10-14",
    "LATEST_FIREFOX_DEVEL_VERSION": "107.0b9",
    "LATEST_FIREFOX_OLDER_VERSION": "3.6.28",
    "LATEST_FIREFOX_RELEASED_DEVEL_VERSION": "107.0b9",
    "LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION": "106.0.5",
    "NEXT_MERGE_DATE": "2022-11-14",
    "NEXT_RELEASE_DATE": "2022-11-15",
    "NEXT_SOFTFREEZE_DATE": "2022-11-10",
    "NEXT_STRINGFREEZE_DATE": "2022-11-11"
}
```